# Change language of Aloha-Editor

Tags: javascript, html, internationalization, aloha-editor

I want to use the [Aloha-Editor](http://aloha-editor.org) for one of my projects. The default project language is german, but I can't find any way to change the language of the editor. (Searched the web and the Guides of their website.)

The only thing I found is how to use i18n when developing a plugin for the editor but not how to set the language in the current stable version.

This is what I did:

```
<!-- load the jQuery and require.js libraries -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.aloha-editor.org/latest/lib/require.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.aloha-editor.org/latest/lib/vendor/jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>

<!-- load the Aloha Editor core and some plugins -->
<script src="http://cdn.aloha-editor.org/latest/lib/aloha.js"
        data-aloha-plugins="common/ui,
                            common/format,
                            common/list,
                            common/link,
                            common/highlighteditables">
</script>

<!-- load the Aloha Editor CSS styles -->
<link href="http://cdn.aloha-editor.org/latest/css/aloha.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<!-- make all elements with class="editable" editable with Aloha Editor -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    Aloha.ready( function() {
        var $ = Aloha.jQuery;
        $('.editable').aloha();
    });
</script>
```

Does anyone know what I need to add or change to get the editor in an other language?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first I found something in the [Aloha Guide about Localization](http://www.xebia.com/sites/all/libraries/aloha/doc/guides/using_aloha.html#localization) but doing this didn't work for me.

Than I had a look at the demo pages and came to this working solution. I had to add the following javascript before I include `require.js` and `aloha.js`

```
<script language="javascript">
    Aloha = window.Aloha || {};
    Aloha.settings = {
        locale: 'de'
    };
</script>
```

Then the Aloha script automatically loads the i18n files for the chosen language. I used a local version of aloha and did not test it with the version from `http://cdn.aloha-editor.org/latest`. My version was 0.22.7.

Comment: For some reason, I had to remove the `common/block` plugin to get it work

Answer (score 1):

you can download other languages [here](http://gengo.com/string/p/aloha-editor-1/)  there is more information available in the [help file](http://gengo.com/string/help/importing_and_downloading/)
You can change the master language at any time in your project via Admin->Languages.

hope this helps

Rachel

Comment: I have all the language files in js format, but I don't know how to use them. Isn't gengo only for developing new plugins or providing new languages for existing ones or the core?
When I downloaded the language file I don't undersand how to load in in my application.

Comment: according to their issues log you just have to set the locale in the config file